# VSCode: how to customize syntax coloring of expressions by the use of regex?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

I do not want to customize the syntax colors of regex in code, but I want to customize the syntax colors of specific things with the help of regex, for example if I want all jquery elements to be green I would use a regex like so (more or less): `\$\(".*"\)` because jquery elements look like this $("*random-element-name*")

My question is how to either set textmate scopes or semantic tokens for regexes or just straight up customize colors by using regex somewhere, whether in vscode, in themes, or with an extension (I saw some similar extension but sadly they dont support regex)

thanks

Comment: The Highlight extension can do what you want.  And have a look at the `Scope Inspector` in vscode: `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` (in the Command Palette) to see if the elements, like jquery ellements, have a unique scope that you can target.

Comment: you can also look at `Highlight` extension

Comment: thank you, the highlight extension is exactly what I was looking for.